# Remover barra branca do topo do layout

Tags: menu, e-commerce

Instalei o Prestashop 1.6.0.9 e veio uma barra branca no topo do layout. Por favor, como remover essa barra?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dê mais pormenores da sua dúvida. Isso é algum complemento HTML? Assim a sua pergunta vai se manter encerrada.

Comment: Essa pergunta está sendo debatida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2605/pergunta-negativada-e-marcada-para-fechar

Answer (score 0):

A versão atual é 1.6.9.14.
Se está fazendo uma instalação nova, prefira a versão estável mais recente.
https://www.prestashop.com/en/download

Quanto ao problema sobre a "barra branca", pode ser algo no theme (template).

Para depurar, teste mudando para o theme padrão do PrestaShop. Caso o mesmo problema ocorra no theme padrão, então provavelmente há algum problema na plataforma ou em configurações.

Caso não apresente o mesmo problema com o theme padrão, provavelmente é problema no theme customizado.

Caso detecte que problema no theme customizado, verifique se está usando utf8 without bom.
Geralmente o bom caracter do UTF8 causa uma quebra no topo.

Comment: Obrigado. Modifiquei o utf-8 para o iso-8859-1 e o problema persiste. Estou no tema padrão, default.

Comment: Leia novamente o que postei e poderá perceber que não postei uma solução. Não é exatamente isso que sugeri que fizesse...